# glibc error running a .net core self contained executable on linux

Tags: c#, linux, visual-studio-2019, glibc, .net-core-3.1

I am compiling a .Net Core 3.1 self contained executable with the `linux-x64` RID.
When I try to run the executable on my Debian `Linux c00kb0xA 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2+deb10u1 (2020-06-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux` I get the folling errors.

`./Business Connectivity Service: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: version 'GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./Business Connectivity Service)`

`./Business Connectivity Service: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.4' not found (required by ./Business Connectivity Service)`

`./Business Connectivity Service: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version 'GLIBC_2.3' not found (required by ./Business Connectivity Service)`

I cannot seem to find a way around it. Is there a way to find out what exactly I am doing in my executable that needs theese dependencies? Or can I somehow ship them with my self contained executable? Or better yet, can I somehow compile against another glibc?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try to deploy application.  https://wakeupandcode.com/deploying-asp-net-core-3-1-to-azure-app-service/

Comment: No Azure involved.

Comment: Still if you build on one machine you have to deploy on second machine if the Net versions are not the same.

Comment: Huh? But they are self contained, You don't need to install .net on target machine.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. Like I said, I deployed as `linux-x64`.

Comment: I think error is due to the setup of Business Connectivity Sevice.  See : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10540/deploy_rpd.htm#BIEMG1177

Comment: There are no data sources. It's a simple application running CRUD tasks on file system.

Comment: A file a database that you read/write/update.  So your CRUD must setup the datasource.

Answer (score 0):

These error messages are completely nonsensical: the required version information is actually present in those libraries. Given that the rest of the system appears to working as intended (so the glibc binaries are probably not corrupted), it's reasonable to assume that `Business Connectivity Service` was not built correctly and contains invalid ELF data.

Comment: Hey Florian Weimer , thanks for your input. Do you have any idea on how to debug? I haven't customized anything on the build process. All I did was ticket the "single executable" button in VS2019.

Comment: If you could upload a binary that reproduces the issue somewhere, I can have a look to figure out what's wrong with it. It's either that, or single-stepping through glibc dynamic loader yourself. 8-)

Comment: That would be incredible :)
I have uploaded the file here: https://gofile.io/d/c5oGa7
Please let me know if you need any other info. Big thanks in advance!

Comment: @SinnedLolwut It would be interesting to hear if this was resolved, and if so, what the resolution was.

Comment: @PerLundberg unfortunately no, it has not been resolved.